# semicircle centered at chord center

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, shapes

I need a semicircle node centred at `chord center`.  The positioning is achieved with the option `anchor`, but the external lines are still directed to `center`.  Is it possible to direct lines to `chord center` as well?

MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [semicircle,draw,shape border rotate=180,anchor=chord center,outer sep=0,inner sep=0.2cm] (a) at (1,1) {};
\draw (0,0) -- (a);
\draw[densely dashed] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: with \draw (0,0) -- (a.north);

Comment: @pascal974 Yes, but in this case line will not be hidden behind the node.

Comment: if fill=whire is acceptable for you 
\node (a) at (1,1){};
  \draw (0,0) -- (a);
  \node [semicircle,draw,shape border rotate=180,anchor=chord center,outer sep=0,inner sep=0.2cm,fill=white] at (a) {};

Comment: No, nodes usually only find the border point from the `center` anchor. In this case you should be able to use `(a.225)` instead. Anything more automatic will be a shape-dependent solution including some calculation. Alternatively, you could as hidden circle node with it's center at `a.north` and use that instead of `a`. Again, an automatic approach would have to figure out on which side of the semicircle the line needs to be connected to.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The problem here is just an example, the actual angle I use is not 225 degrees.

Comment: That's what I feared. Then a more automatic approach is needed. Alternatively, we could try to create a new shape. How should lines be connected when they come from the straight side? Just directly to the chord center?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Fortunately I don't have any lines on the top side, so it does not matter.  Whatever is easier.

Comment: Maybe use a `circle` shape and clip it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short of defining a new shape, here's a cheaty version with another circle node around it.

For this, I'll add the anchor `semicircle center` to the shape which always sits in the middle of the chord, independently of the outer sep.

This allows you to place the shape on the `semicircle center` without changing the outer seps.

Then we add another `circle` node that has the same (outer) radius as the semicircle. This gets the same name as the semicircle but with a `'` added.

Technically, we could extract the radius from the shape itself but the `through` library makes it very easy. (It measures the distance between the `at` and the `through` point and sets that as the `minimum size` of the node.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, through}
\makeatletter
\pgfutil@namedef{pgf@anchor@semicircle@semicircle center}{%
  \pgfpointadd{\pgf@sh@reanchor{semicircle}{chord center}}{%
    \installsemicircleparameters\pgfpointpolar{\rotate+90}{\outersep}}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  circle around semi/.style={
    append after command={[every node/.code=]%
    node[at=(\tikzlastnode.semicircle center),
    circle through=(\tikzlastnode.apex), overlay, 
    anchor=center, name=\tikzlastnode', inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt,
    path only]{}}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
\node [
  semicircle, circle around semi, draw,
  shape border rotate=180,
  anchor=semicircle center,
  inner sep=0.2cm
] (a) at (1,1) {};
\draw[red] (0,0) -- (a');
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikz\draw[ultra thick]
  (0,0) .. controls +(30:1) and +(135:2) .. (2,2)
  foreach[count=\i from 0, evaluate=\i as \c using \i/4*100]
    \pos in {.125, .333, .5, .75, .95}{
    node[fill=red!\c!blue, draw=blue!\c!red, fill, thin, sloped,
    semicircle, circle around semi, pos=\pos, anchor=semicircle center](@){}
    (@') foreach \ang in {0,15,...,359}{edge[thin] ++(\ang:.3)}
  };
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good!  This actually gave me an idea.  I am simply drawing a named invisible circle and unnamed visible semicircle with the same `minimum width` (with `inner sep = 0`).  It is less verbose and easier to maintain.  After all, it appears only few times in the whole document. (And I actually understand what is going on :P)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe clipping could work (but maybe not in your specific case, and positioning text inside the semicircle would need adjustment):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}
\clip (0.5,1) rectangle +(1,-1);
\node [circle, draw, outer sep=0, inner sep=0.25cm] (a) at (1,1) {};
\end{scope}

\draw[line cap=rect] (a.east) -- (a.west);
\draw[red] (0,0) -- (a);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From my comment, we can work around the problem with `\fill`

**The code**

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\colorlet{pagebackground}{yellow!10}
\pagecolor{pagebackground}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (a) at (1,1);
  \draw [red](0,0) -- (a);
  \node [semicircle,draw,shape border rotate=180,anchor=chord center,outer sep=0cm,inner sep=0.2cm,fill=pagebackground] at (a) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I always want to keep the code as simple as possible (KISS) and that I understand it and can actually maintain it. So based on @Qrrbrbirlbel's solution, I am going with this code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\newcommand{\semicircleup}[4]{%
\node[circle,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0,minimum width=2*#3] (#1) at #2 {};
\node[semicircle,shape border rotate=180,anchor=chord center,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0,minimum width=2*#3,#4] at (#1) {};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\semicircleup{a}{(1,1)}{0.5cm}{draw,fill=white}
\draw (0,0) -- (a);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It draws a named invisible circle node (to crop the lines) and an unnamed visible semicircle node with the same minimum width (with `inner sep=0`).

Additional advantage (which is important to me) is that no additional library is used.

But I will still accept @Qrrbrbirlbel's answer as cudos for his idea.